# How to make Google sheet click a link at a specified time automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, whatsapp

I am trying to automate sending WhatsApp messages at the specified time without human interference. I have come up with a way to create links for sending messages, this is the only part that's left/ So I want to write a function/app script for the same
I have as of now come up with

```
function CustomTDSFunction(inputx,inputy) {
  function setUpTrigger(inputx) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(sendWhatsappurl)
      .timeBased()
      .at(new Date(inputx))
      .create(); 
    }
 
   function sendWhatsappurl(inputy) {
     const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(inputy)
     Logger.log(res.getContentText()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want this based on user, or standardize timing for whole operation , just want to know  when and how you want to set the timing and trigger the function?

Comment: I want the timings to be variable, as well as the link

Comment: `I want the timings to be variable` ?? Are you running this function by using it as a custom function in sheet?

Comment: I think I forgot to clarify this but 
inputx= date
inputy=Message url

Comment: I want the timings to be variable ?? Are you running this function by using it as a custom function in sheet? 

Yes

Comment: How do you call `CustomTDSFunction`? More importantly how are you calling the inner functions? How many messages are you sending? Becuase there is a limit to the number of triggers you can have simultaneously

Comment: You can't set more than 20 Trigger/User for this script ,here user is you, [see quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)